# Amazon Webservices AWS Why is there always one micro instance running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a medium instance in AWS EC2 but there is always popping up a t1.micro instance beside it. When i terminate that micro instance a new one is popping up almost immediately. I wanted to set up an environment for the case of backup of our physical system dies. In the mean time there must be no costs or as low as possible. I am afraid the t1.micro instance wil consume credits on storage volume, traffic or other resources.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you originally setup the micro instance with auto-scaling/elastic beanstalk? If so you may have inadvertently left rules in place such that when the instance stops responding, AWS is spinning up a new one to replace the non-responding one.